# I'm getting error while running wcf

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I have hosted service on local IIS

I don't know why this error is coming when I test the service on browser
service working fine when I run from visual studio but when I hosted it on IIS its not working

I am doing this first time. Service is working fine when I run from visual studio but when I hosted it on IIS its not working

following is screenshot of error page.

[image]

Comment: Do as the error says, configure your `/wcf/` virtual directory as an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set following in service model

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="SyncWebServices.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basichttp" contract="SyncWebServices.Service1">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basichttp" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:25:00" sendTimeout="00:25:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="4294967296" transferMode="Streamed">
   <readerQuotas maxDepth="4500000" maxStringContentLength="4500000" maxBytesPerRead="40960000" maxNameTableCharCount="250000000" maxArrayLength="4500000" />
      <security mode="None">
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="true" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```